# python find_element_by_css_selector(value) returns None

Tags: python, html, css, linux, selenium

Below represents the element tag from where I got the element by its CSS selector "#xwt_widget_navigation__slidemenu__SlideOutNavigationButton_1"

```
<div class="xwtSlideMenuLevel0 hasIcon xwtSlideOutNavigationButton xwtSlideOutNavigationButtonFocused dijitFocused" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick: _onItemClick, onmouseenter: _mouseEnter, onmouseleave: _mouseLeave" id="xwt_widget_navigation__slidemenu__SlideOutNavigationButton_1" widgetid="xwt_widget_navigation__slidemenu__SlideOutNavigationButton_1">
    <div class="xwtSlideOutNavigationButtonInner" tabindex="0" role="button" data-dojo-attach-point="buttonNode,focusNode" title="Topology">
        <div class="xwtSlideOutNavigationButtonIcon topologyIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode">
        </div>
        <div class="xwtSlideOutNavigationButtonTitle" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode">
            <a href="#menuItem=%2Ftopology_nav_item_id" class="xwtSlideOutNavigationButtonLink" tabindex="-1">Topology</a>
        </div>
        <div class="xwtSlideOutNavigationArrow" data-dojo-attach-point="arrowNode">
            <span class="xwtSlideOutNavigationArrowIcon"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is when I do a

```
topo = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("xwt_widget_navigation__slidemenu__SlideOutNavigationButton_1")
topo.click()
```

This returns a None, no error or any sort.Am running this on a Linux cmd line and as such using the pyvirtualdisplay. When I do a screenshot it doesn't show that anything happened but when I do a debug using the pdb.set_trace() to step through the code it works. I have looked at the examples on StackOverflow and elsewhere but I couldn't find anything similar or helpful. Can someone tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the manual step you are trying to automate? Are you trying to click on `Topology`?

Comment: Are you clicking immediately on page load? sometimes selenium will act before the button is clickable

Comment: *This returns a None*... Are you sure that `find_element_by_css_selector()` returns `None`?

Comment: @DebanjanB I am trying to click on a button called topology that goes to another page and the topology button is on the man page as well as the other pages

Comment: @StevenBlack No i have a time sleep of 25 seconds before the click because i thought that it was loading too fast

Comment: @Andersson Positive and there is no helpful explaination on there as to what None means. Funny this is when i step through it using terminal debug command it works because i take a screen shot there after.

Comment: Check the button is inside frame/iframe

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `#` as your css_selector is basically using the element id. Try the following:

```
topo = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#xwt_widget_navigation__slidemenu__SlideOutNavigationButton_1")
```

Or

```
topo = driver.find_element_by_id("xwt_widget_navigation__slidemenu__SlideOutNavigationButton_1")
```

Comment: I tried that before i posted this question, it didnt solve it.